# How to create a MS-Word-Form-Region which allows above-insertion?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-office, ms-word

I want to create a Form in Microsoft Word which is quite dynamic and enables the user to add multiple regions. The relevant data contains date-specific events which are sorted descendant. If you insert a new event, it has to appear on top of the list of regions.

As far as I know, you can only insert new regions under the last region. Is there a possibility to change this OR do I have to implement a snippet with Word-Macros to enable it?

EDIT (Curriculum Vitae - Example):

- Primary School - 19xx - 19xx  (I would call this line a 'region')
- College - 19xx - 19xx
- '__' - Date1 - Date2   (+)

So this is sorted in ascending order. WRONG! If i press the +-Button a new region is inserted underneath. I want to achieve something like this:

- '__' - Date1 - Date2   (+)
- College - 19xx - 19xx
- Primary School - 19xx - 19xx

A new region is inserted above automatically.

Comment: May we have an example or sample of what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: what do you mean by `region`? In MS Word there isn't any related name type of object so you need to explain more clearly.

Comment: Have you tried using bookmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a new region above an old one, it's as simple as clicking right on an existing region and "Insert element above".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj889465.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you in need to inserting a text in a word document in MS Word, something like this,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/212682?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

VBA method using bookmarks:

1. Define a bookmark where you want to add the new texts, e.g. after a header but before the other regions.
2. Add a VBA code module and enter the following macro:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub AddNewLine(psText As String)
       '***** Go to bookmark
       Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="[NAMEOFBOOKMARK]"
       '***** Place cursor at end of bookmark
       Selection.Collapse Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
       '***** Add new line
       Selection.TypeParagraph
       '***** Add text or whatever
       Selection.TypeText psText
   End Sub
   ```
3. Replace the line `Selection.TypeText psText` with whaterver it is that you want to add - my example just enters the text-string from the sub parameter.

Comment: I am completely happy with my solution. But does your suggestion only work with plain text or is it possible to "copy" content controls, too? This is what I was needing.

Comment: My suggestion as it stands only works for adding text. It should be possible to copy ContentControls also, but I haven't tried it. At least they are accessible through the word object model, as in `ThisDocument.ContentControls.Item(1).Copy`.